# Only show image if it's available

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

How can I edit the code below, so there's no code if no @business.logo is available.

```
= image_tag @business.logo(:thumbnail), :class=> "img-rounded"
```

This shows up currently when no image has been uploaded:

```
<img alt="Thumbnail" class="img-rounded"   src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/callred/businesses/logos/000/000/034/thumbnail/">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
= image_tag(@business.logo(:thumbnail), :class=> "img-rounded") if @business.logo
```

update

should ask `if @business.logo.present?`

`@business.logo` returns `Paperclip::Attachment` object which is always true

Comment: When I tried that, the empty image block is still there.

Comment: = image_tag(@business.logo(:thumbnail), :class=> "img-rounded") unless @business.logo.blank?

Answer (score 1):

Got it! Here's the code that worked for me

```
- if @business.logo.present?
  = image_tag @business.logo(:thumbnail), :class=> "img-rounded"
```